# Merge conditions to one place

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, cursor

There are two functions: one returns records of workers who have certain tasks to work with and the other one returns the tasks for a particular worker. These two functions have cursors with the same conditions in the WHERE clause.

My question is, how can I define these conditions in a single place? Then my code won't break [DRY principle](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself).

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: I wouldn't like to use REF CURSORS because they are unreliable.

Comment: Voting to close, you need to supply way more details than that, we are not mindreaders.

Comment: Please could you show us the code for both functions?

Comment: @Johan - you don't have to be a mindreader to understand what they're getting at, although obviously it's not the work of a native English speaker.

Answer (score 4):

I think a sensible rule of thumb with `DRY` (Don't repeat yourself) is triangulation: if the same logic exists in three places it is worth the effort of extracting it into its own module.  But don't bother if it only exists in two places.

However, you aren't really repeating yourself, are you?  What you have is *two different queries* returning two different resultsets (one is WORKERS the other is TASKS) which just happen to have some bits of their WHERE clauses in common.  That's not proper repetition.

If you try to root out everything single instance where two lines of code do the same thing you will end up with a horribly unreadable and unmaintainable programs.  Remember that DRY was formulated by [Andy Hunt and Dave Thomas](http://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html), who call themselves Pragmatic Programmers for a very good reason: apply the principle sensibly and understand why you're doing it, rather than blindly following dogma.

Answer (score 3):

Addressing your reservations about REF CURSORs, why do you think they are unreliable?  I've never had any problems with them.  What might well give you grief is using dynamic SQL to populate ref cursors.  But that's a function of trying to remove imaginary duplication, and is nothing to do with the use of cursor variables as such.